# transformation matrices

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I've been reviewing some material on affine and projective (or is it perspective?) transformations. I've reviewed the contents of PIL and wikipedia. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find details that specify how to form the matrices for an affine or projective transform on an image. Wikipedia's article seems to deviate a bit from other resources I've discovered.

Are there any resources on the web that briefly describe not only those operations, but, how to implement them?

Keep in mind, I'd like to be able to understand what matlab's maketform function is doing for 'affine' and 'projective' transformations.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A good resource on affine transforms and creating the matrix is here: http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/affine.htm

Comment: incredible link - do you know of anything similar for projective transforms?